# Jest - Cannot test a cookie after signing up a user

Tags: node.js, cookies, jestjs

I'm testing a cookie where after I signup successfully, I set a token in a response cookie.
unfortunately my test is not passing. I'm using cookie-parser npm version 1.4.6.
When I investigate what is the reason for this, in my response I just get an empty string.
In my user model I have set httpOnly to false and secure to false if we're are not in production environment. Here is the sequence of the  test flow:

signup.test.js:

```
it("sets a cookie after successful signup", async () => {
    const res = request(app)
      .post("/signup")
      .send(fakeUserData)
      .expect(StatusCodes.CREATED);

    expect(res.get("Set-Cookie")).toBeDefined();
  });
```

controller user.js:

```
const SignUp = async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, name } = req.body;

  const exitingUser = await UserModel.findOne({ email });

  if (exitingUser) throw new BadRequest("Email in use");

  const user = await new UserModel({ email, password, name });

  user.save();

  sendTokenResponse(user, StatusCodes.CREATED, res);
};
```

sendTokenResponse function:

```
const sendTokenResponse = (user, statusCode, res) => {
  // Generate Token for user
  user.attachCookiesToResponse({ res });
  res.status(statusCode).json({
    data: [
      {
        success: true,
        user,
      },
    ],
  });
};
```

attachCookiesToResponse function in user Model:

```
UserSchema.methods.attachCookiesToResponse = function ({ res }) {
  const token = this.getSignedJwtToken();

  res.cookie("token", token, {
    httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod",
    expires: moment().add(1, "d").toDate(),
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod",
  });
};
```

getSignedJwtToken function in user model

```
UserSchema.methods.getSignedJwtToken = function () {
  return jwt.sign(
    { id: this._id, email: this.email, role: this.role, name: this.name },
    process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    { expiresIn: process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRE }
  );
};
```

When I test my API with Postman, I receive the cookie.

Can someone explain me why I'm getting a empty string in the response cookies property?
here is the result of the response cookies when doing an investigation:

```
 Test {
      _events: [Object: null prototype] {
        end: [Function: bound onceWrapper] { listener: [Function: bound ] }
      },
      _eventsCount: 1,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _enableHttp2: false,
      _agent: false,
      _formData: null,
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://129.9.9.9:99999/signup',
      _header: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
      header: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      writable: true,
      _redirects: 0,
      _maxRedirects: 0,
      cookies: '',
      qs: {},
      _query: [],
      qsRaw: [],
      _redirectList: [],
      _streamRequest: false,
      _lookup: undefined,
      _buffer: true,
      app: <ref *1> Server {
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          request: [Function],
          connection: [Function: connectionListener]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 0,
        _handle: TCP {
          reading: false,
          onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 0,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 60000,
        requestTimeout: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::0',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 15326
      },
      _asserts: [ [Function (anonymous)] ],
      _server: <ref *1> Server {
        maxHeaderSize: undefined,
        insecureHTTPParser: undefined,
        _events: [Object: null prototype] {
          request: [Function],
          connection: [Function: connectionListener]
        },
        _eventsCount: 2,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _connections: 0,
        _handle: TCP {
          reading: false,
          onconnection: [Function: onconnection],
          [Symbol(owner_symbol)]: [Circular *1]
        },
        _usingWorkers: false,
        _workers: [],
        _unref: false,
        allowHalfOpen: true,
        pauseOnConnect: false,
        httpAllowHalfOpen: false,
        timeout: 0,
        keepAliveTimeout: 5000,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        headersTimeout: 60000,
        requestTimeout: 0,
        _connectionKey: '6::::0',
        [Symbol(IncomingMessage)]: [Function: IncomingMessage],
        [Symbol(ServerResponse)]: [Function: ServerResponse],
        [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
        [Symbol(async_id_symbol)]: 15326
      },
      _data: { name: 'Jefferson', email: 'test1@mail.com', password: 'abcdefg' },
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of stackoverflow user **slideshowp2** i have manage to resolve this issue.
When I was reproducing the problem by following the [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) procedure mentioned by **slideshowp2**, I had noticed that I was passing only my router url which is **"/signup"** instead of full application url which is **"/api/v1/signup"**

Once again I'm thanking **slideshowp2** for saving my day.