# Supertest Module - throwing expected 201 "Created", got 404 "Not Found" when using supertest end method

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest

based on my question I have post on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71981908/jest-cannot-test-a-cookie-after-signing-up-a-user), I'm doing a research to resolve this issue. I'm about to find the answer but for some reason which I don't know, I'm getting an error when i use the supertest end method:

```
it("sets a cookie after successful signup", async () => {
    request(app)
      .post("/signup")
      .send(fakeUserData)
      .expect(StatusCodes.CREATED)
      .end((err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err.message);
        }
      });
  });
```

Can someone explain if this is a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you in advaced.

Comment: Please provide a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the info @slideshowp2, I will look into it and will come back.

Comment: @slideshowp2 thank you very much again for your tip, I have resolve the problem. I was passing the wrong URL.